# DataSpell running very slow

Tags: performance, machine-learning, jupyter-notebook, jetbrains-ide, dataspell

My projects run so much slower in JetBrains DataSpell rather than Jupyter notebook. When I try to hyper-tune my parameters using sklearn it takes nearly 50 times longer than when on Jupyter notebook.

Does anyone have any solutions?

Comment: Ive switched to Pycharm since I mainly used jupyter. Pycharm is just better in most aspects.